# JQuery - Unchecking Checkboxes Not Performing Desired Action

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I am wanting to implement a checkbox that will display a div if checked and hide the div if unchecked.

This is what I have so far:

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function handleVersions(div) {
   var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

   j$(document).ready(function() {      
     j$('.check').on('click', function () {
       if (j$(div).hasClass('visible')){
          j$(div).hide();
          j$(div).removeClass('visible');
        }
       else {
          j$(div).show();
          j$(div).addClass('visible');
        }
     });
    });
 }
</script>
```

Div that calls the Script:

```
  <div class="check">
     <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!row.selected}">
       <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" onsubmit="handleVersions({!row.section})" rerender="innerCheckboxes"/>
     </apex:inputCheckbox> 
  </div>
```

Div that should be refreshed from the called Script:

```
  <div id="{!row.section}" class="notVisible">
       <apex:pageBlock id="innerCheckboxes">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
               <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!row.versionOptions}">
                     <apex:selectOptions value="{!row.versionCheckboxes}"/>
                </apex:selectCheckboxes> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
   </div>
```

The CSS classes "visible" and "notVisible" are just custom CSS classes that have only one attribute, "display:block" and "display:none" respectively.

When I click the checkbox, the div will show. However I want the div to hide when I unclick the checkbox. Presently, I can only get the div to hide when I unclick then re-click the checkbox. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `div` in the javascript?  A variable holding the correct div selector?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the `toggle()` function of the jQuery. Why you are using the `click` trigger for the div? Use it for the checkbox! Set the ID to the checkbox and listen on it in your jQuery script:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!row.selected}" id="myCheBox">
...
</apex:inputCheckbox> 


j$(document).ready(function() {      
    j$('[id$=myCheBox]').on('click', function () {
        j$('.notVisible').toggle();
    });
});
```